# Observer for fire&forget Task

Tags: asp.net-core

Disclaimer : I may have a bad idea !

I have a middleware on ASP.NET 5. 
This middleware process the request and start a new `Task`. The task is mainly for statistics purposes.
The middleware do not care of the result of this task.

For performances reason, I would like to continue the ASP.NET pipeline without awaiting for the "background" task.

I see three way to implement this :

1/ Start the task, no `await` or `.Wait()`. Do no care about unobserved exception.

2/ Register the task within an "`observer`". The observer will observer all the tasks until the application ends.

3/ Use a service bus and/or a kind of worker role / WebJob.

I do not like the solution 1/.

The solution 3/ seems excessive.

The solution 2/ is OK to me, with something like that :

```
public class TaskObserver : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();
    public void RegisterTask(Task task)
    {
        _tasks.Add(task)
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks.ToArray());
    }
}

// somewhere in the service configuration...
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<TaskObserver>();
```

The Observer will be disposed at the end application by its container.
I could even add a `Timer` for cleaning completed tasks at regular interval.

Is the 2/ solution correct in an ASP.NET 5 context ?

Comment: Update: [Implementing background tasks in .NET Core 2.x webapps or microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom line is that ASP.NET was not designed for doing work that is *not* an HTTP request. There's a [few different ways to try to hack together a fire-and-forget situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) (as I describe on my blog), but none of them are foolproof.

WebJobs, on the other hand, are designed for *exactly* this scenario. So the best answer is "just use WebJobs". Give them a try; they're probably not as hard as you think.

However, if you really want to take the less-reliable route of doing background work in the ASP.NET AppDomain, then there are varying degrees of hacks to try. E.g., if you're willing to take a dependency on the full .NET framework (not just core), then you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Comment: I think you're right on the mark (as always!) except that `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` isn't included with ASP.NET 5. Since the hosting environment itself has changed substantially, might the issues with tasks as background threads have changed, too?

Comment: I don't recommend adding background tasks in your web app. The reason is that your website can shutdown if there are no requests for a while. Like Stephen said, use webjobs or another service that does background processing.

Comment: @MattDeKrey: I expect QBWI will be included in `dnx452`/`dnx46`, once they're released. AFAIK there's no plans to put it in `dnxcore`.

Comment: HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem is not available in ASP.NET 5, don't even bother trying to use it. System.Web isn't around so it might do unexpected things or just outright explode.

Comment: Are WebJobs an Azure-only feature?

Comment: @TamusJRoyce: These days I'd recommend Azure Functions (equivalent to AWS Lambdas).

Answer (score 0):

Hangfire (google Hangfire.io) now has ASP.NET core support and even works with async tasks, it's built for exactly this purpose.

Comment: saw "per developer / year" but missed perpetual. very promising!